# how to draw an editable polygon on google map on android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to draw a polygon on the user location on google map and that the polygon will be editable by the user.
Does google map API have the option to set the polygon as editable??

for now, I succeeded to create the polygon around the user position.
but not to edit the polygon...

here is my code:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //if red it's ok. permission granted in MainActivity and android studio is stupid
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            if(firstLocationCapture && mMap.getMyLocation() != null) {
                firstLocationCapture = false;
                //set the map center to the user position
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude() , mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude()), 16));

                Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                        .add(
                                new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude() + 0.001, mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude() + 0.001),
                                new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude() + 0.001, mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude() - 0.001),
                                new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude() - 0.001, mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude() - 0.001),
                                new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude() - 0.001, mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude() + 0.001))
                        .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#39e600"))
                        .fillColor(Color.argb(50, 0, 255, 0))
                        .strokeWidth(2));

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!